# set utf-8 encoding jquery response

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8

I'm using an ajax request with $.ajax to get an php array  with `fgetcsv`,
but the response has encoding problems.

How I can set the response encoding?

The php file charset is set `('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` on the php file, which manage the ajax request.

Comment: whats the ``contentType`` of your ajax?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu ,it's the default charset, it's utf-8 I think

Comment: i mean for your ajax. maybe paste your ajax?

Comment: No until tommorrow sorry